# creating table and using if statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

[image]

[image]

I have this question which I don't really understand

I need help understanding or answering it

Comment: Let me first say this is not a real-world scenario, but I guess they're trying to get you to apply different concepts.  What are you having trouble understanding about the question?  In a nutshell, they're asking you to grab all the rows where RACES_COMPLETED is between 500 and 900 which is a basic SELECT statement.  What is your experience with SQL Server?

Comment: No too advanced, but I understand it well

Comment: I think someone wants you to select some rows into a temporary table using SQL Server Management Studio. Printing the messages would take another SQL statement. There are other possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
--Create the table on the fly with the condition stated
SELECT
    TEAM_NAME,
    RACES_COMPETED
INTO [TOP TEAMS] 
FROM YourTable
WHERE RACES_COMPETED >= 500 and RACES_COMPETED <= 900


--Store the number of teams in the new table in a variable for ease of use
DECLARE @topTeams INT
SET @topTeams = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [TOP TEAMS])


--If there are teams in the table, print the number of teams. If there aren't any, print the other statment
IF @topTeams > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'NO. OF TOP TEAMS: ' + CAST(@topTeams AS VARCHAR)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'NO TOP TEAMS EXIST'
    END
```

**HERE IS THE SAME CODE USING A TEMP TALBE**

```
--Drop the TEMP TABLE if it exists
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TOP_TEAMS') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TOP_TEAMS

--Create the table on the fly with the condition stated
SELECT
    TEAM_NAME,
    RACES_COMPETED
INTO #TOP_TEAMS
FROM YourTable
WHERE RACES_COMPETED >= 500 and RACES_COMPETED <= 900


--Store the number of teams in the new table in a variable for ease of use
DECLARE @topTeams INT
SET @topTeams = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TOP_TEAMS)


--If there are teams in the table, print the number of teams. If there aren't any, print the other statment
IF @topTeams > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'NO. OF TOP TEAMS: ' + CAST(@topTeams AS VARCHAR)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'NO TOP TEAMS EXIST'
    END
```

Comment: Thank you very much.much appreciated